# User profile Badge progress bar shows a completed bar, not the next one to get

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

Noticed the bug on SuperUser profile page, Newest badge is also **Supporter** and next badge is also **Supporter**.

[image]

Comment: That happens. It's caching.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Thanks. Do I've to do anything which would trigger to update the cache?

Comment: Nope. It is just set so a certain interval. Just wait...

Comment: I know the *in-bar* progress is updated live (or at least on page load).  Not sure if the *badge selection* could be cached.  Will try to have someone take a peek and see if we can repro it.